# How to intercept mobile traffic on Android?

Tags: android, network-traffic

I have a device (videocamera) with Android inside.
I have root access via ADB to the OS of the videocamera.

The camera sends data to the internet using a SIM card.
Is there a way to redirect the mobile traffic to a proxy, so that I could research it?

1) Seems that an apk like ProxyDroid may help, but it lacks the command line interface.
2) I tried redirecting the traffic using Access Point Name (APN), but is did not help.

Comment: Have you seen: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98287/how-to-set-wifi-proxy-via-adb-shell

Comment: Thank you. But would it intercept mobile traffic as well? Will give it a try anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The common tool for this is Charles Proxy, but you'd need to be able to install certificates on the host device.